# How can I add buttons to the container from an action listener in JAVA?

Tags: java

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class StudentDatabase extends JFrame {
    JLabel jl= new JLabel("Name:");
    JLabel jl1= new JLabel("Class");
    JLabel jl2= new JLabel("Reg number");
    JLabel jl3= new JLabel("Semester");
    JLabel jl4= new JLabel("GPA");
    public JLabel jl5= new JLabel("Semester");
    JLabel jl6= new JLabel("Credit Hours");
    JLabel jl7= new JLabel("Semester 2");
    JButton jb= new JButton("SAVE");
    String name, cLass, regn;
    JTextField jt= new JTextField("  Enter  Name");
    JTextField jt1= new JTextField("   Enter Class");
    JTextField jt2= new JTextField("  Enter  Reg number");
    JTextField jt3= new JTextField("  Enter  Semester");
    JTextField jt4= new JTextField("  GPA    ");
    JTextField jt5= new JTextField("  Enter Semester GPA");
    JTextField jt6= new JTextField("  Enter  CH");
    public Container c= this.getContentPane();
    StudentDatabase(){

        c.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        this.setBounds(100,100,300,400);
        c.add(jl);
        c.add(jt);
        c.add(jl1);
        c.add(jt1);
        c.add(jl2);
        c.add(jt2);
        c.add(jl3);
        c.add(jt3);
        c.add(jl4);
        c.add(jt4);

        jb.addActionListener(new mal());
        name=jt.getText();
        cLass=jt1.getText();
        regn=jt2.getText();

        c.add(jb);
        this.setVisible(true);
        c.setVisible(true);


    }
    protected class mal implements ActionListener {
        String name, cLass, regn,s,g,ch;

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

            s=jt3.getText();
            s=s.trim();
            System.out.println("abnc");
            System.out.println(s);
            if(s.equals("1")){

                c.add(jl5);
                c.add(jt5);
                c.add(jl6);
                c.add(jt6);
                c.setVisible(true);

                System.out.println(s);
                ch=jt6.getText();
                System.out.println(ch);
                jt4.setText(s);
            }

        }
    }

}
```

So this is my code. I want some of the buttons to be displayed when my SAVE button is pressed . And for that I've added them in action listener. But the problem  is that the buttons are not displayed when my action  listener is called. How can i solve this problem?

Comment: You must revalidate after adding components to an already visible container. `container.revalidate()` instead of trying to set it visible again

Comment: @VinceEmigh 1 more question. How can I make SAVE button disappear after container is revalidated? And how can I make  button appear at next line in flowlayout?

Comment: Also you should avoid using trivial variable names such as `b` or `s` unless they are being used for trivial purposes such as the index of a for loop. Instead use names that have some meaning so that your code becomes self-commenting. I wonder if you really want to use a CardLayout to swap JPanels...

Comment: Just remove it from the container: `container.remove(comp);` and revalidate after. As for FlowLayout, I'm gonna be honest, I NEVER use it, so I can't really help you there (I use GridBagLayout on most occasions). You should check out Oracle's tutorial on it: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html

Comment: FlowLayout does not support "line breaks". There are some alternatives (e.g. one JPanel with FlowLayout for each "line"), and websearches about this issue bring some results (sometimes called "WrappingFlowLayout" or similar) - can't give a particular recommendation here, thus only a comment

Comment: @VinceEmigh In this program when the buttons are added then the value of text field jt6 "enter ch" gets stored in variable ch in action listener. But I want to store the value which I add to it when it is created(at run time). How can I do that?